# How to display the numeric keyboard directly in the Android

Tags: java, android

I m developing an android application.

I have an edit text (password), when I typing on, the android system keyboard appear.

By default when the android keyboard is called, it displays the letter keyboard. I want that it displays directly the numeric keyboard instead of the letter keyboard when I call the android keyboard. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You can provide your own `Keyboard` and `KeyboardView`. Where's the output going?

Comment: @MD your answer is the right answer. Please make it back and I will accept it